# Error getting list of files from a particular directory on apache server

Tags: java, android, apache

I am getting error on fetching the list of files from apache server using serverFileList(). Android is crashing on making of object of ApacheURLLister class. I am beginner in Android Development. Please tell me how to fetch list of files from the server?

```
Public List serverFileList(){
        URL url;
        List serverDir = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://192.168.137.1/temp/");
            ApacheURLLister lister = new ApacheURLLister();
            serverDir = lister.listAll(url);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERROR ON GETTING FILE","Error is " +e);
        }
        return serverDir;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just simply pull list of files on the server. You need to give name of particular file to be fetched therefore you have to write code in such a way that you specify which file is to be fetched from server. This can be resolved also through server sided scripting